# Computing Limits of Multivariable Functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have seen this problem on an exam I was looking at:

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{y}{1+xy} - \frac{1 - y\sin(\frac{\pi x}{y})}{\arctan(x)}$

Compute the limit:

$g(x) = \lim_{y\to\infty} f(x,y)$

I am confused on how to solve this limit however. Wouldn't the value of the limit also depend on $x$ ? (this problem lets $x$ be independent?)

Comment: Assume x a constant, apply limit for y and get a function dependent only on x.

Comment: Okay, I have done this for the first term and it was easy enough with L'Hospitals, but how do I do it for the second term?

Comment: @patrickh Do you remember how to evaluate the limit $\lim_{\theta\to 0} \sin (c\cdot\theta)/\theta$?

Comment: @Stahl yes that would be $c$

Comment: @patrickh Then note that $\lim_{y\to\infty} f(y)=\lim_{\theta\to 0^+} f(1/\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are having problems with the second term,
note that you can write it as
$$\frac{1-\frac{\sin\pi xp}{p}}{tan^{-1}x}$$
(here $\frac{1}{p}=y$ and as y goes to $\infty$, p goes to $0$) leaving the $tan^{-1}x$ alone,
our job is to find
$$\lim_{p\to 0} \frac{\sin\pi xp}{p}$$=
$$\lim_{p\to 0} \frac{\sin\pi xp}{\pi xp}\cdot \pi x$$
=$$\pi x$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y) = \frac{y}{1+xy} - \frac{1-ysin(\frac{\pi x}{y})}{\arctan(x)}$, let's modify our function
$$\frac{y}{1+xy} - \frac{1-ysin(\frac{\pi x}{y})}{\arctan(x)} = \frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{xy}+1} - \frac{1-ysin(\frac{\pi x}{y})}{\arctan(x)},$$
now let $z = \frac{1}{y}$, hence
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} f(x,y) = \lim_{z\rightarrow 0} f(x,\frac{1}{z})=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\frac{z}{x}+1} - \frac{1-\frac{1}{z}sin(z\pi x)}{\arctan(x)},$$
clearly $\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\frac{z}{x}+1} \rightarrow \frac{1}{x},$
let's have a closer look at $\frac{1-\frac{1}{z}sin(z\pi x)}{\arctan(x)}$.

Using Taylor series we can write 
$$\frac{1}{z}sin(z\pi x) = \frac{1}{z}\Big(z\pi x + \mathcal{O}(z^3)\Big)=\pi x + \mathcal{O}(z^2),$$
Can you go from here?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Recall that the sine function satisfies the inequalities

$$\left|z-\frac16 z^3\right| \le |\sin(z)|\le |z|$$

Now let $z=\pi x/y$.